# On the efficiency of using views of views in MySQL

Tags: mysql, view

I have recently been introduced to the concept of views and I am finding them a great help for splitting complex queries into parts.

My question is wether there are any efficiency disadvantages when I start making queries from views which they are in turn queries from other views, etc...

So I would for example have:

```
view1 -> query from tables A, B & C
view2 -> query from tables D, E & F
view3 -> query joining view1 & view2
```

Will there be any speed disadvantage when querying view3 instead of designing a single query that joins tables A, B, C, D, E & F?

And in case I would choose to use the views approach, does it matter, wether I have ORDER BY clauses in the design of view1, view2 & view3 or is it better that I don´t put any ORDER BY clause in any of the views and I just use ORDER BY when I query view3?

Thank you very much for your help!
Boga.

Comment: `Order By` usually doesn't make much difference to your results UNLESS you want to get for e.g. `top 5 with max revenue`... `names in alphabetical order with first 10 customers`... and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `order by` see [CREATE VIEW Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-view.html)

> ORDER BY is permitted in a view definition, but it is ignored if you select from a view using a statement that has its own ORDER BY.

And here on [View Processing Algorithms](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/view-algorithms.html), you can see how MySQL processes selects on views. As always, it depends. ;-)

It seems that the `MERGE` algorithm is the most efficient, because algorithm `temptable` copies the view results to a temporary table first and does the query on that. But you cannot always use merge, see the last section

> If the MERGE algorithm cannot be used, a temporary table must be used instead. MERGE cannot be used if the view contains any of the following constructs:
>
> - Aggregate functions (SUM(), MIN(), MAX(), COUNT(), and so forth)
> - DISTINCT
> - GROUP BY
> - HAVING
> - LIMIT
> - UNION or UNION ALL
> - Subquery in the select list
> - Refers only to literal values (in this case, there is no underlying table)